# MongoDB query used with java

Tags: java, mongodb

Is there any way to execute Mongo query in Java like this?

```
client.execute("db.name.find({'age':'20'})");
```

Comment: Read this http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/2.13/getting-started/quick-tour/

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to do it like this:

```
db.getCollection("name").find(new Document("age", "20"));
```

The drivers use a direct connection to the mongod server and are not executing shell commands.